# Count data in mysql json by key

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I work in mysql 8 and have a problem on counting data in json format field. This is my table:

[image]

I want to count data in `absensi` field where the key is "657" and the value is "0". So, by this table it must give me result 4.

I tried to use `JSON_EXTRACT(absensi, '$.657')` but always give me some error `[42000][3143] Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 6.`

Can you help me how to solved this problem?

Thank's in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `key` value is a `string`. Treat it as `string` instead of `integer`.

```
select json_extract(absensi, '$."657"')
```

If you are using your field as `key` value, you can build the `parameter` using `concat()` function.

```
select json_extract(absensi, concat('$."', fieldA, '"')) from test;
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=kioM4HC55p).

Comment: Omg, sorry my bad. Thank for your answer. But can we using another field to extract it? like json_extract(absensi, field_name) so I can using it in subquery

Comment: @AdiSparta, please provide sample data and update your question.

Comment: @AdiSparta . . . Or better yet, ask a *new* question, with sample data as *text* in the question and perhaps a db/SQL fiddle.

Comment: @EdBangga thanks, your updated answer was what I wanted. I will used your second query from my problem. Thanks